# postgres 9.3 slow query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

1. put my schema

```sql
member_action_records
                       Table "public.member_action_records"
    Column     |            Type             |              Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 id            | uuid                        | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 member_id     | uuid                        |
 location      | geography(Point,4326)       |
 ip            | character varying(255)      |
 source        | integer                     | default 0
 channel_id    | character varying(255)      |
 action_type   | character varying(255)      | default 0
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone |
 longitude     | character varying(255)      |
 latitude      | character varying(255)      |
 app_version   | character varying(255)      |
 agent         | text                        |
 address       | character varying(255)      |
 province      | character varying(255)      |
 city          | character varying(255)      |
 district      | character varying(255)      |
 street        | character varying(255)      |
 street_number | character varying(255)      |
Indexes:
    "member_action_records_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_member_action_records_on_channel_id" btree (channel_id)
    "index_member_action_records_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "index_member_action_records_on_member_id" btree (member_id)
    "index_member_action_records_on_source" btree (source)
```

version: postgres:9.3
data size : 12+ million

2. explan sql
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpmL8.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmjF5.jpg
3. analyse 
   I think postgres index base programe！
   sometime postgres think use member_id index before result always use file sort
   so postgres use action_type direct get result
4. think everyone
   i'm english very bad,forgive me

Comment: Can you share `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` Output? Your links show estimates, not actual statistics

Comment: Also, if possible you should upgrade to v. 9.5 or higher. 9.3 is no longer supported

Comment: image link already show result,please,What else do you need

Comment: yes,if upgrade 9.3+,without happen slow query

Comment: You showed `EXPLAIN select...` — please show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE select...`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select ...`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (no screen shots please) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: And as richyen already mentioned you should really upgrade to an up-to-date version (11 or 12)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm8nV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRVqP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxQdI.png